# How far can the male ribcage expand until a surgery is medically necessary?

Tags: biology

I am Loki,god of mischief and trickery. After being kicked out of Asgard, I came to live among humans and pass my time by pranking them. One day, I  created a magical pool filled with powerful Mana instead of water. Anyone who enters the pool will become magically impregnated with a spirit. As a joke, I enticed hundreds of males to bath in this pool, telling them that it is a good isolated place to relax. No doubt that in a few weeks, they will be met with a nasty surprise.

The looks on the faces of these males when they realise what has happened will be priceless, and I now aim to sit back and watch the hilarity ensue. Abortion is not an option, seeing as the spirit isn't human and can't be aborted through normal means. The only option left is a cesarian section, in which the spirit will ultimately have to be delivered through surgery. From an anatomical standpoint, the size of your rib bones is constant and they cannot be made wider, except when accommodating a child. Can the male ribcage expand in the same way a female can? How far can it expand until a C-section is necessary?

Comment: Shall we take it that you mean "hip bones" and "pelvis"? What you are asking makes no sense otherwise. That aside, this doesn't seem to be about world-building as written, care to [edit] to make it on-topic?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about hip bones and not ribcages, this still isnt possible unless the spirit does some more magic.

There is a rare (I just looked it up and found out its not that rare and even accounts for 4 to 10% of all maternal deaths, yikes https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.livescience.com/amp/51711-ectopic-pregnancy.html) very dangerous but (edit: NOT) survivable condition in which a fertilized egg somehow lands outside of the mother's womb. This will almost always kill the egg or when the egg manages to nestle itself there it'll kill whichever organ the egg has latched on to as it leeches it for nutrients (if you ever wonder why a female body treats a baby like a parasite for the duration of the pregnancy wonder no more). But it is theoretically possible that it'll nestle in fat tissue and grows there, which will eventually cause rupturing of the surrounding tissues as only the uterus has the capacity to expand that much for the baby. So a man, sorry a male, that has this spirit will likely be doing an Alien scene where the offspring bursts out of his stomach to save you a cesarian section before a live, healthy baby will be in need of rescue.